# String split when input string is unknown (Java Android SMS split and forward)

Tags: java, android, sms, split, broadcastreceiver

My android application takes sms messages from a `BroadcastReceiver` and copies the message into a new sms. Then forwards it. Due to technical reasons I must to split the sms and copy only the portions after `split[2]`:

```
  public string splitAndReturnRest(String inputStr)
  {
     String[] split = inputStr.split("\\s"); // split where spaces
     // now ignore split[0], split[1], split [2], copy rest of the split parts into
     String restOfTheSplits=//copy rest of the splits except split[0], split[1], split[2]

      return restOfTheSplits;
 }
```

The problem is I can't just hard code it.  I do not know how many parts the message contains. So the number of elements after `split[2]` is unknown to me and may change every time. Perhaps I need some kind of for loop, or a different split criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After split[2], use the following....

```
String restOfTheSplits = null;
for (int i=3 ; i<split.length; i++)
{
  restOfTheSplits = restOfTheSplits + split[i];
}
return restOfTheSplits
```

Its even better if you use `StringBuilder` to get the `restOfTheSplits` and then convert it to String and return it....

Comment: Thanks .. just a few mins before your answer I figured out this prob .. But thanks any ways :)

Comment: @sans481 Thanks, for saying something that i hesitated.